# why Booleans slow my computer more than expected

Tags: modifiers

[image: mesh with boolean cuts in array]

Hi, I'm on a 3.2Ghz 6core AMD processor, 16Gb Ram, GTX 1050Ti vid card.
Blender 2.91, via Steam ( so auto updates)
usually works fine, so I'm suspicious of how i'm working.

The mesh was a curve, converted to mesh, cleaned of excess Verts and extruded.
The cylinders (holes 6mm/8mm/10mm) are the default 32 sided, I've changed the dimensions and applied transforms.
Difference boolean calls on the 'Holes colection' which has the cylinders in it.
a couple of arrays spread out the cylinders/holes which display as wire.

it.. chuggs.. soo... slow..

is 32 sides on the cylinders considered excessive?
should I get rid of the arrays and make instances of the cylinders?
have i missed something obvious?

Comment: I don't know if you're using one of the latest versions, but now it automatically sets the mode to "Exact" which is really really slow compared to the "Fast" method. Please show the boolean settings

Comment: this is the answer!

Comment: Unluckily Boolean is super laggy, just get used to it. And set autosave frequency to as small as possible in preferences :D

Answer (score 7):

Blender 2.91 comes with a new "exact" solver for Booleans. The old one is still around but by default EXACT it enabled.

There's the option "fast" in the Boolean Modifier (this enables the old algorithm/solver). If you click it you get way better performance but a less accurate boolean operation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

3.2GHz is a bit slower than many modern CPU's. Also Blender's calculations are going to be single-threaded so you're not really going to be able to make use of the multiple cores. The only thing that is multithreaded in Blender is rendering.

I would get [HWInfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/) or use Resource Monitor to check your CPU core activity, RAM and disk usage while its slow compared to when it's running smoothly. That should give you an idea of where the bottleneck is (if there is one).

Also as Gorgious noted, there is a [new(ish) "Exact"](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Modeling) solver for boolean modifier/tool which can slow it down a bit.